# The iterated Kleene closure of an alphabet

Tags: definition, formal-languages

The Kleene closure of an alphabet $A$ is the set of all finite sequences with terms in $A$. However, I am interested in defining something like an "iterated" Kleene closure. Let me give an example to illustrate. Consider the alphabet $\{a,b\}$. Some elements of the iterated Kleene closure are $a$, $b$, $(a,b,b)$, $(a,b,(a,b))$, $(a,(a,(a,a),a),a)$. Basically, you take the Kleene closure of the set and iterate it $\omega$ times. What I am looking for is the formal definition of my concept. Also, has any mathematician defined this concept previously?

Comment: I think I've heard computer scientists refer to it as "ragged nested lists" or something like that.  And it would be canonically isomorphic to the set of binary trees with leaf nodes labelled by the original alphabet (using the usual representation where a list is converted to a cons-type expression).  Not sure if that's along the lines of what you're asking for.

Comment: These are called "labeled trees". The labels are the elements of the original alphabet.

Comment: You don't have associativity?

Comment: You could consider a colimit to have a nice definition

Comment: For questions like this, I think you should clarify what you mean by (or what you're trying to achieve with) a "formal definition". The definition you've given is quite clear and shouldn't be hard to express "formally", but the details will depend on the choice of formal system and how you choose to represent lists in it.